# RxJS chain Promises passing previous values

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, rxjs

I would like to chain a few Promises while being able to read previous results in next step of a pipe and return array of results in the end.
I created a function that looks something like this:

```
await from(items).pipe(
        mergeMap(async (item) => {
            const product = await this.getProduct()
            return {
                item,
                product,
            };
        }),
        mergeMap(async ({ item, product }) => {
            const price = await this.getPrice(product);
            return {
                item,
                product,
                price,
            }
        }),
        mergeMap(async ({ item, product, price }) => {
            return itemRepository.save({ item, productId: product.id, priceId: price.id });
        }),
        toArray()
).toPromise()
```

This worked fine when functions were synchronous, but now next steps don't wait until previous ones are completed. I would like to make them wait.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The only way to make this work is by making sure that `mergeMap` itself is aware of promises, and itself returns a promise that you `await`. So share the definition of mergeMap, or write a new version that's promise aware.

Comment: What do you mean by share the definition?

Comment: `mergeMap` is defined somewhere. If it's not currently promise-aware, we'll need to understand how `mergeMap` was written so a promise-aware version can be written.

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to use `pipe` here? It doesn't seem to fit the requirements. Just write a single `async function` with three `await`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RxJS `mergeMap` operator expects a function that returns an `Observable`. You won't be able to return an `Observable` from an `async` function, because an `async` function always returns a `Promise`.

I suggest you to refactor your code like this:

```
await from(items)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((item) =>
      from(this.getProduct().then((product) => ({ item, product })))
    ),
    mergeMap(({ item, product }) =>
      from(this.getPrice(product).then((price) => ({ item, product, price })))
    ),
    mergeMap(({ item, product, price }) =>
      from(
        itemRepository.save({ item, productId: product.id, priceId: price.id })
      )
    ),
    toArray()
  )
  .toPromise();
```

You could also not use RxJS at all and get rid of the Promises to Observables conversions:

```
await Promise.all(
  items.map(async (item) => {
    const product = await this.getProduct();
    const price = await this.getPrice(product);
    return itemRepository.save({
      item,
      productId: product.id,
      priceId: price.id,
    });
  })
);
```

Comment: mergeMap will accept an promise, observable, array, or any kind of iterate (array-like) object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do something like this

```
const promiseFunction = async (item) => {
      const product = await this.getProduct()
      const price = await this.getPrice(product);
      const lastResult = itemRepository.save({ item, productId: product.id, priceId: price.id })
      return {
            item,
            product,
            price,
            lastResult
        };

}

await from(items).pipe(switchMap(item =>from(promiseFunction(item)),toArray()).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above. It's generally better to stick to either observables or promises wherever possible. They do have interoperability, but this is a feature best used when mixing libraries that use one or the other.

Mixing the two willy-nilly is likely to create some unexpected situations that arise from their eager vs lazy semantics or just from needing to understand two libraries instead of simply one.

There are already some examples above of how this can be done with promises. Here's an example of how the main body can be done without them. (I left the `await` & `toPromise` at the start and end as I have have no idea the context this is used in.

```ts
await from(items).pipe(
  mergeMap(item => this.getProduct().pipe(
    map(product => ({
      item,
      product
    }))
  )),
  mergeMap(({product, ...rest}) => this.getPrice(product).pipe(
    map(price => ({
      product,
      price,
      ...rest
    }))
  )),
  mergeMap(({ item, product, price }) => this.itemRepository.save({
    item, 
    productId: product.id, 
    priceId: price.id
  })),
  toArray()
).toPromise();
```